# Low Quality Review Queue: Add a new button to require more details to code-only answers

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts

While reviewing the Low Quality queue, we are constantly facing **code-only answers**.

Most of the time, such an answer does provide an answer to the question, so we can't choose "**Recommend Deletion**".

However most of the time, while providing an answer to the question, the answer is not good, because it doesn't explain to the user what the issue was or how the user should handle the problem. So I am often reluctant to choose "**Looks OK**", even if I finally do it.

The best solution actually is obviously to leave a comment requesting the answerer to add more details. However, this is time wasting process if you don't have a pre-formatted comment stored somewhere, which is finally rarely the case when you visit SO on many computers.

My proposal is to add a new button that would:

1. automatically add a nice standard comment requesting for details and linking to the [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.
2. eventually provide an option to move the answer to the improvement queue.

Comment: Or a fix at the source of the problem by adding a requirement that answers can not be code only when submitting an answer?

Comment: @TimWilkinson: Yes, but then you need to be able to filter out "try this", "try that", "try tihs", and the like...

Comment: What I think would be better would be to have SO integrate the [AutoReviewComments user script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) into the site.  Then we can have custom auto comments associated to our user account so they follow us no matter where what device we are on.  Then we can customize the comments to our liking but also have the couple mouse click ease of use.

Comment: Another top-level review action, alongside Looks OK, Edit, and Delete/Recommend Deletion? Or another auto-comment option in the Delete dialog?

Comment: @NathanTuggy another top-level action because the aim is not to delete the answer